# selecting mysql table that has been requested from product detail

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question about selecting multiple tables of MySQL in PHP.
I have two tables Allopathic & Nutraceutical and one Order Form for all products of these two categories.

I want to use a single Order form for all products and I am successful to fetch the product name in the form field. What should I type in replace of allopathic to become single order form for both tables Allopathic and Nutraceutical?
Please help.

My SQL query is given below:

```
<?php  $sql = "SELECT * FROM allopathic where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";    

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $id=$row['id'];

?>
```

You can visit my example on my website at [www.msgpharmaceutical.com/allopathic.php](http://www.msgpharmaceutical.com/allopathic.php) 
browse this product and click on order form in product detail page.
Thank you.

Comment: *The requested URL /allopathic.php was not found on this server.*

Comment: here is the url you can visit.
http://msgpharmaceutical.com/pharma/allopathic.php

Comment: Are the columns the same in both tables? If they are, you can use a union.

Comment: No sir. There are two different tables in mysql. 
allopathic | nutraceutical

Comment: Are allopathic and nutraceutical tables associated by their IDs? Or is each product in each table completely separate.

Comment: There are separate tables for each product Allopathic and Nutraceutical.

Answer (score 0):

you can get data from database using two query and then use it in single form.

Like for allopathic :

```
<?php  $sql = "SELECT * FROM allopathic where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";    

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_allopathic = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id_a=$row_allopathic ['id'];

?>
```

and for nutraceutical :

```
<?php  $sql = "SELECT * FROM nutraceutical where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";    

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_mutraceutical = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id_n=$row_mutraceutical ['id'];

?>
```

Now you can use $row_allopathic and $row_mutraceutial in your form.
Combined Query:

```
<?php  $sql = "SELECT * FROM allopathic where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";    

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_allopathic = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id_a=$row_allopathic ['id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM nutraceutical where id='".$_REQUEST['id']."'";    

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$row_mutraceutical = $result->fetch_assoc();

$id_n=$row_mutraceutical ['id'];
?>
```

Comment: yes you can put these two queries in your order-form if you want to show these two table data.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the product type a parameter to the script.

```
<?php
$type = isset($_REQUEST['type']) ? $_REQUEST['type'] : "allo";

if ($type == "allo") {
    // Code to display allopathic products
} else {
    // Code to display nutraceutical products
}
```

Comment: I don't know what that is. This is for the browsing page that you mentioned in the comment.

Comment: Okay Thank you sir for helping me.

Comment: In the order form you can include the type as a hidden input for each product, so you query from the appropriate table.